# LivePatch & secure boot self-signed kernel modules

Tags: kernel, secure-boot, canonical-livepatch, self-signed

It seems that [LivePatch works with SecureBoot](https://lwn.net/Articles/704056/), but what about self-signed kernel modules?

If a kernel patch is (auto)applied via livepatch, and I am using secure boot, **do I have to re-sign the kernel modules that were active before the patch was applied**? Normally you need to re-sign the modules upon kernel updates.

Comment: How should we know? Try it and post it you have a problem lol

Comment: The purpose of the stack community is to try to draw from each others' experiences. Imagine how much noise we would have if everyone that didn't know an answer said "How should we know?" Funny I have to mention this to someone who has 650x more points than me, but whatever. And yes, if I don't get an answer I will make sure to post it here if/when I find out on my own. But I can't control the insertion of a livepatch, so have patience.

Comment: I understand but your scenario is very specific to your hardware and to some extent it does not sound if you have a problem or not as it is untested.

Comment: Specific to my hardware? Kernel modules are a pretty common thing these days, and none of the ones I use are for hardware reasons.